# refer elements in bag in Pig on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have an alias called student, the data structure is like this (result of command `describe`),

```
studentIDInt:int,courses:bag{(courseId:int,testID:int,score:int)}
```

Then I am trying to filter students by score, but met with such Pig parse error, if anyone have any good ideas, it will be great. Thanks.

Confused about the additional tuple reported in the error message.

```
student = filter student by courses.score > 3;

incompatible types in GreaterThan Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(score:int)  right hand score:int
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: (INT)courses.score > 3 maybe?

Comment: @BurakKarasoy, thanks and vote up. I think the data structure has an additional tuple, this is the error about? How do you think?

Comment: @BurakKarasoy, tried here is the new error message `Cannot cast bag with schema :bag{:tuple(score:int)} to int`

Comment: I don't know I'm a beginner about pig. I just tried to make a guess.

Comment: filter student by SUM(courses.score)>3 will work

Comment: @SurenderRaja, thanks and vote up. I want to filter by individual score and SUM will aggregate all scores of all courses? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly. Possible solution is first flatten, filter and than group again

```
flat_student = foreach student generate studentIDInt, flatten(courses);
filtered_student = filter flat_student by score > 3;
final_student = group filtered_student by studentIDInt;
```

Another way is writing custom FilterFunc, so it's up to you what to choose.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, vote up. And why need an additional flatten? Thanks.

Comment: You can't access elements in bag directly (without writing custom UDF), typical pig filter functions expect scalars. That means you can access element in a tuple, but not in the bag.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, is courses in my example a typical bag, or a bag with an additional layer of nesting with tuple?

Comment: Hi Alexey, vote up and if you refer to this line `X = FILTER A BY f3 == 3;` of Pig tutorial https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#FILTER, filter could operate on bag (in this case `X` is a big). Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: Hi Alexey, if you could comment on my question above, it will be great. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Alexey, mark your reply as answer.